Помогите выяснить почему программа бесконечно выполняется
У меня есть 2 файла. В одном ("sorts.py") содержатся методы сортировки списков:
def bubble_sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1] :
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
    return arr

def shell_sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    gap = n // 2
    while gap > 0:
        for i in range(gap, n):
            temp = arr[i]
            j = i
            while j >= gap and arr[j - gap] > temp:
                arr[j] = arr[j - gap]
                j -= gap
            arr[j] = temp
        gap //= 2
    return arr

def quicksort(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    pivot = arr[len(arr) // 2]
    less = [i for i in arr if i < pivot]
    equal = [i for i in arr if i == pivot]
    greater = [i for i in arr if i > pivot]
    return quicksort(less) + equal + quicksort(greater)

def check_sorted(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
            return False
    return True

В другом ("main.py") подключается модуль sorts.py и сортируется 3 последовательности: отсортированная, случайно сгенерированная и отсортированная в обратном порядке, тремя методами, указанными выше, а после подсчитывается время сортировки. Данные выводятся в отдельный текстовый файл.
import random
import time
import sorts


def measure_time(func, arr):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    func(arr)
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    return end_time - start_time

def generate_sequences(n):
    sorted_seq = list(range(n))
    reversed_seq = list(range(n - 1, -1, -1))
    random_seq = random.sample(range(n), n)
    return sorted_seq, reversed_seq, random_seq

def main():
    ns = [10, 20, 50000, 100000]
    results = []
    headers = ["N", "Тип последовательности", "Метод сортировки", "Время выполнения (сек)"]

    for n in ns:
        sorted_seq, reversed_seq, random_seq = generate_sequences(n)
        sequences = {"Отсортированная": sorted_seq, "Обратно отсортированная": reversed_seq, "Случайная": random_seq}
        # Убираем встроенную сортировку
        sort_methods = {
            "Пузырьковая сортировка": sorts.bubble_sort,
            "Сортировка Шелла": sorts.shell_sort,
            "Быстрая сортировка": sorts.quicksort,
        }

        for seq_name, original_seq in sequences.items():
            for method_name, method in sort_methods.items():
                seq_copy = original_seq[:]
                time_taken = measure_time(method, seq_copy)
                results.append([n, seq_name, method_name, time_taken])

    with open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write("".join(header.ljust(25) for header in headers) + "\n")
        for row in results:
            f.write("".join(str(item).ljust(25) for item in row) + "\n")

    print("Результаты сохранены в файл output.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Проблема в том, что при списках небольшой длины всё выполняется успешно, но когда длина списка, например, 50000 или 100000, то она начинает выполнятся бесконечно.
Что можно с этим сделать?

Снимаю шляпу перед героями, пишущими сортировку списков вручную, а "профессоров", которые возможно ДО СИХ ПОР задают писать эти сортировки студентов, просто обожествляю. Не прошло и ста лет, как команды сортировки встроены в язык, работают быстро и правильно. Но мы не сдадимся!

@FoxFox, возражу вам. Сортировка - прекрасная учебная задача, на которой можно понять и почувствовать что такое сложность алгоритма, насколько разнообразно такая простая задача может быть поставлена, насколько разнообразными могут быть методы её решения. Сортировку можно  сравнить с теоремой Пифагора, которая была доказана давно и сотней разных способов, но если вы хотите заниматься математикой, вам полезно придумать своё доказательство теоремы Пифагора.

Труд облагораживает. Во времена готовых модулей, постановок задач для ИИ и голосового управления компьютерами в сетях - самое оно, пузырьковая сортировка списков. Главное, чтоб все были заняты и было куда время убить. Странно, а почему не пишут приложения типа Photoshopа какого-нибудь на ассемблере - ну, чтоб почувствовать как каждый пиксель назначается. А ещё предлагаю письма друг другу писать в конвертах, а то труд почтальона совсем уж не в почёте - надо ж почувствовать каждую строчку, каждое скрипение пера, которое макаем в чернильницу! :-))))

Я начал программировать в 1993-м. Сортировка в язык, который я осваивал первым, уже тогда была встроена. Я был очень удивлён, когда сыну в школе в прошлом году дали задание по Питону написать эту дурь. Я конечно написал, но не знал смеяться над школьной программой или плакать.

@FoxFox, я до сих пор пользуюсь тетрадью и ручкой для вычислений и доказательств. Не потому что мне нравиться марать бумагу, а потому что это пока эффективней чем делать всё на компе. И навыки устного счёта сочетаю с использованием компьютера. Потому что это эффективней чем под каждую идею писать программку проверяющую её. И приложения типа Photoshop оптимизированы на ассемблере (это одна из причин, почему его так трудно заменить другим редактором графики, и почему его так трудно переносить между операционными системами и процессорами).

На здоровье. А я не пишу ручкой, я спрашиваю как решить задачу у ИИ или прошу рассказать мне о какой-то математической теме. Мне время дорого. И мне 60, кстати. Я ж написал выше - труд облагораживает. Я программист, поэтому не будем манипулировать терминами впустую. Photoshop - НЕ ПИСАЛСЯ на ассемблере. Оптимизации, неоптимизации - даром  не нужны современнным программистам эти подробности. Если б его писали на ассемблере, закончили бы лет через десять от сегодняшнего дня считая.

О каких-таких трудностях переноса Photoshop идёт речь? Photoshop изначально заточен под яблочников, работает в винде. Насчёт Windows XP, которую называют Линуксом, не помню, и мне неинтересно что там. "приложения типа Photoshop" - мало ли на свете писателей и фотошопов? Проблемы переносимости и криворукого программирования - их проблемы, больше ничьи. Я работаю с профессионалами и устанавливаю клиентам софт профессионалов, а не любителей.

Дело в том, что пузырьковая сортировка (как и выбором, и вставками, и некоторые другие) имеет квадратичную сложность, т.е. её время выполнения зависит от количества элементов как O(n^2).
Так что для списка длиной 100000 будет выполнено порядка 10^10 операций, что на Python займёт часы или сутки. Практическое применение эти сортировки могут иметь только для малых наборов данных, и сравнение времен стоит проводить, скажем, только до нескольких тысяч элементов.
Другое дело - быстрая сортировка, со временем выполнения порядка O(n*logn), для ваших размеров она будет проходить за секунды (а на компилируемом языке - за миллисекунды)

Вы запускаете сложную программу и гадаете, она повисла из-за ошибки или просто работает долго? Ситуацию портит то, что надо дождаться всех результатов, чтобы разобраться. Упростим всё до предела: одна сортировка, один тест, возможность управлять программой извне.
import random
import time


def measure_time(func, arr):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    func(arr)
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    return end_time - start_time


def bubble_sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1] :
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
    return arr


def main():
    n = int(input())
    seq = random.sample(range(n), n)
    time_taken = measure_time(bubble_sort, seq)
    print(n, time_taken)


main()

Запускаю программу с растущим размером входа:

$ echo 10 | python temp.py
10 2.6152003556489944e-05

$ echo 100 | python temp.py
100 0.0006155550945550203

$ echo 1000 | python temp.py
1000 0.07188936602324247

$ echo 10000 | python temp.py
10000 8.005143661051989


Последний запуск занял восемь секунд. Прогоняю программу на входах, которые отличаются в два раза и так чтобы время работы измерялось в единицах секунд:

$ echo 1000 | python temp.py
1000 0.0722273220308125

$ echo 2000 | python temp.py
2000 0.29628414497710764

$ echo 4000 | python temp.py
4000 1.197030601091683

$ echo 8000 | python temp.py
8000 4.899013999849558


Увеличение размера входа в два раза приводит к увеличению времени работы примерно в четыре раза (нужен навык устного счёта или калькулятор). Так ведут себя программы с квадратичной сложностью.
В предположении квадратичного поведения делаем экстраполяцию. Запускать программу не надо, это просто арифметика, времена вычисляются:



n
t – время работы




8000
5с


16000
≈ 20с


32000
≈ 80с


64000
≈ 320с ≈ 5 минут


128000
≈ 1280с ≈ 21 минута



Всё очень грубо, но особая точность тут не нужна. Сто тысяч элементов будут сортироваться от пяти до двадцати минут. Теперь вы знаете сколько вам нужно ждать чтобы собрать статистику. И у вас есть инструмент чтобы понять какую статистику можно собрать в разумное время, скажем в течении одной минуты.
Похожие тесты имеет смысл повторить для других сортировок и других данных. Затем можно отрегулировать размеры массивов в вашей основной программе и собрать данные по времени работы.

Если переписать функцию пузырьковой сортировки на отдельные переменные, то можно сократить время работы примерно в 2 раза
def bubble_sort2(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    newarr = [0] * n
    maxi = 0
    idx = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1]:
                maxi = arr[j]
                idx = j
        newarr[idx] = maxi
    return newarr

Правда, учитывая ответы Stanislav Volodarskiy и MBo вам это врят ли поможет

Вероятно, вы хотели сделать что-то вроде сортировки выбором в новый массив, только это и не сортировка вовсе...
